# PHP How to create a new array from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with Google Fonts (+600):

```
$google_fonts = array(
"ABeeZee" => "ABeeZee",
"Abel" => "Abel"
//......)
```

And I need this new structure:

```
$google_fonts = array(
array('label' => 'ABeeZee','value' => 'ABeeZee'),
array('label' => 'Abel','value' => 'Abel')
//......)
```

I have this code but it's not working:

```
foreach( $google_fonts as $font ) {
  $google_fonts_array = array(
      'value' => $font,
      'label' => $font,
      'src' => ''
  );    
}
return $google_fonts_array;
```

This array should be used here (it's a type that uses a select box):

```
'choices' => array( //this is one old option
                array(
                    'value' => 'Open Sans',
                    'label' => 'Open Sans',
                    'src' => ''
                ), //and here is how I would retrieve the new array
                $google_fonts_array //or even using it instead of the previous level array, it's not working.
            )
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the array everytime, Do this instead.  (Notice the `[]`)

```
foreach( $google_fonts as $font ) {
  $google_fonts_array[] = array(
      'value' => $font,
      'label' => $font,
      'src' => ''
  );    
}
return $google_fonts_array;
```

Comment: Yes, your point is good. But still it is not working for me. If I use the new structure of the array directly, the values are showed in the select box, so it seems that I'm missing something else in that code... Probably the `return` is not enough. What can I try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already fixed it. I had to use `global $google_fonts_array;` twice, one in the main file of options (it was missing), and the other one into the function where there is the select box. Thanks :)